# UWP: Cannot Implicitly Convert Button to AppBarButton

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

When I run my C# UWP app in debug mode with Visual Studio it works fine, however after trying to Create an App Package, I get an error during the build:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button' to 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.AppBarButton'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I don't actually have any Buttons in the xaml code, they're all AppBarButtons. Can anyone see what I've got wrong? The Xaml is below.

```
<Page
    x:Class="Sheet_Music_Reader.Views.ScoreViewer"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Sheet_Music_Reader.Views"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:muxc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid Margin="0,-125,0,0" Background="{ThemeResource AcrylicInAppFillColorDefaultBrush}">
        <CommandBar DefaultLabelPosition="Right" Height="42" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" >
            <CommandBar.Content>
                <AppBarButton FocusVisualPrimaryThickness="0" FocusVisualSecondaryThickness="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Icon="Back" x:Name="BackButton" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Back" Click="BackButton_Click"/>
            </CommandBar.Content>
            <AppBarSeparator/>
            <AppBarElementContainer>
                <InkToolbar x:Name="inkToolbar" VerticalAlignment="Center"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal" TargetInkCanvas="{x:Bind inkCanvasA}">
                    <InkToolbarCustomToggleButton 
                x:Name="toggleButton" 
                Click="CustomToggle_Click" 
                ToolTipService.ToolTip="Touch Writing">
                        <SymbolIcon Symbol="{x:Bind TouchWritingIcon}"/>
                    </InkToolbarCustomToggleButton>
                </InkToolbar>
            </AppBarElementContainer>
            <AppBarSeparator/>
            <AppBarElementContainer VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <TextBlock Margin="0,0,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="10,0,0,0">Go to page:</TextBlock>
                    <TextBox FocusEngaged="GoToTextBox_FocusEngaged"  AllowFocusWhenDisabled="True" AllowFocusOnInteraction="True" x:Name="GoToTextBox" BorderThickness="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" KeyDown="GoToTextBox_KeyDown" InputScope="Number" IsHitTestVisible="True" IsEnabled="True"/>
                    <AppBarButton  Width="40" Height="45" Click="GoToPage" VerticalAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="0"  Background="Transparent"></AppBarButton>
                </StackPanel>


            </AppBarElementContainer>


            <AppBarSeparator/>
            <AppBarButton Label="Fullscreen" Icon="FullScreen" x:Name="FullscreenButton" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Fullscreen" Click="FullscreenButton_Click"/>

            <AppBarSeparator/>
            

                <AppBarButton Label="Bookmarks" Icon="Bookmarks" x:Name="BookMarksButton" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Bookmarks">
                    <AppBarButton.Flyout>
                        <Flyout Placement="Bottom">
                        <StackPanel Margin="0,20,0,0" Background="Transparent">

                            <StackPanel x:Name="bookmarkstackpanel" Margin="10" Background="Transparent">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="nobookmarkmessage" Text="You have no bookmarks." />
                                <StackPanel x:Name="bookmarkstacker" Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Transparent">


                                        <ListView x:Name="bookmarkslist" Margin="0,0,5,0">
                                            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                                                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                                        <Setter.Value>
                                                            <ControlTemplate>
                                                                <ContentPresenter/>
                                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                                        </Setter.Value>
                                                    </Setter>
                                                </Style>
                                            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                                        </ListView>
                                        <ListView x:Name="bookmarkslistdeleter" Width="53">
                                            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                                                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                                        <Setter.Value>
                                                            <ControlTemplate>
                                                                <ContentPresenter/>
                                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                                        </Setter.Value>
                                                    </Setter>
                                                </Style>
                                            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                                        </ListView>
                                    </StackPanel>


                                </StackPanel>
                                <AppBarButton Content="Create Bookmark" Width="140" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="gray" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="30,0,30,0" FontSize="18" Click="NewBookmarksButton_Click"></AppBarButton>

                            </StackPanel>

                        </Flyout>
                    </AppBarButton.Flyout>
                </AppBarButton>

            

        </CommandBar>



        
        <ProgressRing x:Name="LoadingIndicator" Height="100" Width="100"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="LoadingText" Text="Opening PDF" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" Margin="0,180,0,0"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="LoadingText2" Text="Large documents may take a moment to open for the first time" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="16" Margin="0,270,0,0"/>

        <AppBarButton Width="0" Height="0" x:Name="focusremover"></AppBarButton>



        <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Margin="0,45,0,0" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="DoubleGrid">

            <ScrollViewer x:Name="landscapescroller" ZoomMode="Enabled" MinZoomFactor="1" MaxZoomFactor="7" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                
                <Grid x:Name="biggergrid">


                    <Grid x:Name="landscapeEnclosingGrid">


                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>



                        <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,0,0" x:Name="leftimagegrid">
                            <Image x:Name="leftimage" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="/Assets/enScore-logo-grey-large.png" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>

                        </Grid>

                        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                            <Image x:Name="rightimage" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="/Assets/enScore-logo-grey-large.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>

                        </Grid>

                    </Grid>



                    <InkCanvas x:Name="inkCanvasA" />

    


                </Grid>
                
            </ScrollViewer>
            


        </Grid>


        <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" x:Name="SingleImage" Margin="-1000,45,-1000,0" Grid.Row="1">
            <ScrollViewer  ZoomMode="Enabled" MinZoomFactor="1" MaxZoomFactor="7" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Name="singlescroller">
                <Grid x:Name="biggergridtwo">
                    <Grid x:Name="portraitEnclosingGrid">


                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>

                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>


                        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
                            <Image x:Name="SingleImagefield" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="/Assets/enScore-logo-grey-large.png" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>

                        </Grid>

                    </Grid>

                    <ScrollViewer MinZoomFactor="2" MaxZoomFactor="2" HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled" ZoomMode="Disabled" VerticalScrollMode="Disabled">
                        <InkCanvas x:Name="inkCanvasB" Width="4000"/>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                        


                    
                    
                </Grid>
            </ScrollViewer>

        </Grid>


        <RelativePanel x:Name="PageTurningCanvas" Margin="0,40,0,0">

            <Grid PointerPressed="TurnPageLeftButton_PointerPressed" PointerEntered="Grid_PointerEntered" PointerMoved="Grid_PointerEntered" x:Name="TurnPageLeftButton" RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel="True" Width="100" Opacity="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="Transparent"/>
            <Grid PointerPressed="TurnPageRightButton_PointerPressed" PointerEntered="Grid_PointerEntered" PointerMoved="Grid_PointerEntered" x:Name="TurnPageRightButton" RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel="True" Width="100" Opacity="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Background="Transparent"/>

        </RelativePanel>




    </Grid>
    
    
</Page>
```

Comment: Please post your code-behind event handlers.

Comment: I can’t reproduce your issue based on the above information. Could you please provide us a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) by OneDrive or GitHub?